# TCP transfer in Java is VERY slow

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am doing a program to saturate a link for performance testing in my networking lab, I tried different things, from changing Send and Receive buffers, creating a file and reading it, creating a long array and sending it through the socket all at once: OutputStream.write(byte[])

The array is 1000000 positions length, when I sniff the network traffic, according to the sniffer, the packets have "Data (1460 bytes)" which make me supose that I'm not sending byte by byte.

The bandwidth used is about 8% of the 100Mbps.

I post the relevant code as there is some interaction between client and server which I don't think is relevant:

Client:

```
int car=0;
do {
    car=is.read();
    //System.out.println(car);
    contador++;
} while(car!=104);

Server:

byte dades[]=new byte[1000000];
FileInputStream fis=null;
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("1MB.txt");
    fos.write(dades);
    fos=null;
    File f = new File("1MB.txt");
    fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    step=0;
    correcte=true;
    sck = srvSock.accept();
    sck.setSendBufferSize(65535);
    sck.setReceiveBufferSize(65535);
    os = sck.getOutputStream();
    is = sck.getInputStream();
}

...

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
bis.read(dades);
for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
    os.write(dades);
}
```

In this case I put the last idea I had, to create a file with a million positions byte array and then read this file and write to the socket, before this idea I was sending the byte array.

Another thing which make me believe this is not a byte by byte sending is that in a quad core computer the client uses 25% CPU and uses around 8% of the bandwidth, and in an old computer which is single core (AMD Athlon) it uses 100% of the CPU and just 4% of the bandwidth. The server is not so CPU intensive.

Any ideas??? I feel a little lost right now...

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you tried a buffered outputstream/writer?

Comment: I'm going to try it, there was an error with the constructor...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's related to the fact that client reads data byte by byte, that can force flow control algorithm to limit transmission bandwidth:

```
int car=0;
do {
    car=is.read();
    //System.out.println(car);
    contador++;
} while(car!=104);
```

Try to read data into array instead, or use `BufferedInputStream`:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[65536];
int size = 0;
boolean stop = false;

while (!stop && (size = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (buf[i] == 104) {
            stop = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using BufferedInputStream(InputStream) (as the java doc constructor shows) and returns the error: xception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method BufferedInputStream(InputStream, int) is undefined for the type start

Comment: import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;

Comment: @Carles if an answer is working for you, it's customary to accept the person's answer as correct :)

Comment: Reading byte by byte doesn't do anything to flow control algorithms ecxcept very indirectly. What it does is execute a system call per byte instead of a system call per 8192 bytes in the BufferedInputStream case. This is a major CPU overhead in the receiver. That in turn may cause the reader to read slowly enough that the sending end has to slow down but it's a secondary effect.

Comment: Yep! I wondered something like this just now because the transfer was going at "just" the 87-90%, I checked the task manager and saw that wireshark was using over 800MB of memory, I closed it and then transfers were going at 100% or near, it's amazing how is everything related at some point!!!